# For Loop for Today's date finding nothing

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I've made a spreadsheet like this one before with no issues. It has the same concept but has had errors or does nothing.

In Google Sheets I have a sheet with Names and Birthdates and other information. (Dates are in multiple Columns in different formats to just try and fix this issue. Some are concatenated from a cell with month and another with the day (11 for month, 13 for day to produce "11/13". Or just typed out by hand 11/13, or even with this years date "11/13/2017").

I've simplified my code to show you, which produces no results and no errors.

```
  function birthdays() {

  //Sheets Var List
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var births = ss.getSheetByName('Birthdays');
  var lastRow = births.getLastRow();

  var dateToday = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy");

//Column 10 has the dates manually entered in format MM/dd/yyyy.
//I have added today's date in the list to ensure it has something to find to trigger the message.
//Column 8 has the message I want to show on the date with the same row.
      for (var i = 1; i < lastRow; ++i) {
            if (dateToday == (births.getRange(i, 10).getValue()))
            Browser.msgBox(births.getRange(i, 8).getValue())
      }
  }
```

I've tried this a few ways and was getting method errors with my formatDate in the for loop, likely because that was looking for birthdates coming from cells using concatenate.

I've also thought about getting the dates from my Google Contacts, as they are in there, but I haven't been able to figure out how to search through my contacts group and match the current day with the contacts birthdays.

This is just for fun, and eventually I'll have it send an email to my cellular email which texts me, or even sends a text to the person who has the birthday. Just need to get it to match the birthday to the current date first. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you share an example Google Sheet as well, with the actual data and structure?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/150zH5JViwH2bR9yhLEhIV6Phf8uwMP-EhnmVroGwako/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I should have shared that already. I changed a few things to just not have personal info out in the world. Thank for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.
The sheet didn't have the date cells as a date value or object. It was a string because of the concatenation I did.

Google Sheets has a formula that changes a string to a date value. Used that and it solved the first issue.

The second issue was that my header row was a string and would immediately produce an error, so I changed i's value to be 2 instead of 1 to skip the header row and it resolved everything.